# AppleScript repeated athorisation request for contact access, but only on M1 Processor Mac

Tags: applescript, macos-monterey

Did anybody encounter the problem of MacOS (Monterey) repeatedly asking for authorisation to allow an AppleScript.app to access contacts. The code indeed does use contact application, but on non M1 Mac it asks once, get inserted in the list of apps allowed to access contacts and it does not ask any more. On M1 Mac, it is also listed as with granted access but it keeps asking nevertheless on each run of the script.
The script is also listed in the security - automation section.
Any idea?

Comment: What did you use to build the application?  Is it code-signed?

Comment: Just saved it from script editor as application. If I run it from the script editor then all is good

Comment: Is the M1 Mac using the same version of the OS as the non-M1 Macs?

Comment: yes. This is something I struggle for a while, because customer keeps showing me that when the script runs (as app), he has to click countless time to authorise access to contacts, but I do not have any problems, when I authorise it once, then it does not ask any more. Now I figured out that the only difference is CPU type, found myself an M1 and indeed, now I can reproduce the problem...??? Thanks

Comment: Apple M1 devices have different code signing requirements.  You can try running the app using Rosetta, but a better approach would be to code sign it or make the script read only, as a script typically modifies itself to save properties and globals.  The system will then see it as a different app - one that hasn’t been given permissions.

Comment: Recompiling it on the M1 Mac seems to resolve the issue, although, I'm sure I tried this before too, just on the customer's Mac, this time I did it on mine, strange. Checking the Rosetta checkbox did not help. Thanks for all the suggestions